# How to install Erlang 24.1 on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: amazon-linux-2, erlang

I need to install Erlang 24.1 on Aamazon Linux 2. I am using package cloud script and repos for this but it fails with following message.

```
(venv) [CORP\shiv.d@a-1njrk968l4brs yum.repos.d]$ sudo yum install erlang
Loaded plugins: amzn_workspaces_filter_updates, halt_os_update_check, priorities, update-motd
rabbitmq_erlang/x86_64/signature                                                                                                                                      |  833 B  00:00:00     
rabbitmq_erlang/x86_64/signature                                                                                                                                      | 1.8 kB  00:00:00 !!! 
Not using downloaded rabbitmq_erlang/repomd.xml because it is older than what we have:
  Current   : Fri Oct  1 10:15:14 2021
  Downloaded: Tue Sep 14 08:38:56 2021
rabbitmq_erlang-source/signature                                                                                                                                      |  819 B  00:00:00     
rabbitmq_erlang-source/signature                                                                                                                                      |  951 B  00:00:00 !!! 
rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server-source/signature                                                                                                                             |  836 B  00:00:00     
rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server-source/signature                                                                                                                             | 1.0 kB  00:00:00 !!! 
356 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package erlang.x86_64 0:24.1-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.7.1)(64bit) for package: erlang-24.1-1.el8.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
(venv) [CORP\shiv.d@a-1njrk968l4brs yum.repos.d]$
```

It complains about zlib 1.2.7.1 which is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure, but it might be due to the Linux version n Amazon Linux.

As you can see in the Erlang package name, *erlang.x86_64 0:24.1-1.**el8**.*
It indicate that it is for Enterprise Linux 8.

If you try to run `rpm -E %{rhel}`, it will return you **7**, hence you'll need the erlang that support **el7**